# Python: automatically handle download prompt when opening html file

Tags: python, html, download, plotly

Using Plotly I generate HTML files containing plots of data.

Plotly also provides an option that automatically asks the user to download the plot as `.svg` file when the HTML file is opened.

Is there a way to open these HTML files with python and then automatically save the generated `.svg` file to some location?